# MATLAB: How to subset a multidimensional matrix using 1-D vector indices without for loops?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I am currently looking for an efficient way to slice multidimensional matrices in MATLAB. Ax an example, say I have a multidimensional matrix such as

`A = rand(10,10,10)`

I would like obtain a subset of this matrix (let's call it `B`) at certain indices along each dimension. To do this, I have access to the index vectors along each dimension:

```
ind_1 = [1,4,5]
ind_2 = [1,2]
ind_3 = [1,2]
```

Right now, I am doing this rather inefficiently as follows:

```
N1 = length(ind_1)
N2 = length(ind_2)
N3 = length(ind_3)

B = NaN(N1,N2,N3)

for i = 1:N1
   for j = 1:N2
     for k = 1:N3

      B(i,j,k) = A(ind_1(i),ind_2(j),ind_3(k))

     end
   end
end
```

I suspect there is a smarter way to do this. Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that does not use for loops and could be used for an arbitrary `N` dimensional matrix.

Comment: The difficulty is here the dimensionality, especially if you do not know it at programming time. What I did in the past is putting a slicing string together and then using eval for it. Not nice, but if anyone has a better idea for an arbitrary number of dimensions.

Comment: @Trilarion In that case you can use a comma-separated list generated from a cell array; see my updated answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually it's very simple:

```
B = A(ind_1, ind_2, ind_3);
```

As you see, Matlab indices can be vectors, and then the result is the *Cartesian product* of those vector indices. More information about Matlab indexing can be found [here](http://es.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).

If the *number of dimensions is unknown* at programming time, you can define the indices in a cell aray and then expand into a [comma-separated list](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html):

```
ind = {[1 4 5], [1 2], [1 2]};
B = A(ind{:});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reference data in matrices by simply specifying the indices, like in the following example:

```
B = A(start:stop, :, 2);
```

In the example:

1. `start:stop` gets a range of data between two points
2. `:` gets all entries
3. `2` gets only one entry

In your case, since all your indices are 1D, you could just simply use:

```
C = A(x_index, y_index, z_index);
```